# error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice

Tags: api

I have a question about CUDA_DIR. I created a virtual environment in Anaconda and installed tensorflow_gpu, object_detection API, CUDA, and cuDNN in this environment. However, when I run the
`ssd_efficientdet_d0_512x512_coco17_tpu-8.config file` in the Anaconda command prompt, I encounter the following error.

```
W0518 11:39:20.226400 10040 utils.py:82] Gradients do not exist for variables ['top_bn/gamma:0', 'top_bn/beta:0'] when minimizing the loss. If you're using `model.compile()`, did you forget to provide a `loss` argument?
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
error: Can't find libdevice directory ${CUDA_DIR}/nvvm/libdevice
2023-05-18 11:39:37.593131: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1768] UNKNOWN: JIT compilation failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yunpeng\PycharmProjects\TF2\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 114, in <module>
    tf.compat.v1.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 36, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 308, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 254, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\yunpeng\PycharmProjects\TF2\models\research\object_detection\model_main_tf2.py", line 105, in main
    model_lib_v2.train_loop(
  File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 685, in train_loop
    losses_dict = _dist_train_step(train_input_iter)
  File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.UnknownError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'train_input_images/write_summary/mod' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\threading.py", line 937, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 629, in train_step_fn
      if record_summaries:
    File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 630, in train_step_fn
      tf.compat.v2.summary.image(
    File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\image\summary_v2.py", line 141, in image
      tag=tag, tensor=lazy_tensor, step=step, metadata=summary_metadata
    File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 599, in <lambda>
      lambda: global_step % num_steps_per_iteration == 0):
Node: 'train_input_images/write_summary/mod'
Detected at node 'train_input_images/write_summary/mod' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\threading.py", line 937, in _bootstrap
      self._bootstrap_inner()
    File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\threading.py", line 980, in _bootstrap_inner
      self.run()
    File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 629, in train_step_fn
      if record_summaries:
    File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 630, in train_step_fn
      tf.compat.v2.summary.image(
    File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\image\summary_v2.py", line 141, in image
      tag=tag, tensor=lazy_tensor, step=step, metadata=summary_metadata
    File "C:\Users\yunpeng\anaconda3\envs\tf_2\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 599, in <lambda>
      lambda: global_step % num_steps_per_iteration == 0):
Node: 'train_input_images/write_summary/mod'
2 root error(s) found.
  (0) UNKNOWN:  JIT compilation failed.
         [[{{node train_input_images/write_summary/mod}}]]
         [[train_input_images/write_summary/summary_cond/pivot_t/_1261/_25]]
  (1) UNKNOWN:  JIT compilation failed.
         [[{{node train_input_images/write_summary/mod}}]]
0 successful operations
```

Since I installed CUDA and cuDNN using the "conda install cudatoolkit" method in the Anaconda environment, I don't have the `NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\nvvm` folder. So, how can I resolve this error?Should I download and install cudatoolkit from the CUDA official website and then copy the nvvm folder to the same directory as this file`ssd_efficientdet_d0_512x512_coco17_tpu-8.config file`?